# Css repeatable property

Tags: css, html

I have an HTML source code content which comes from a WYSIWYG editor.

I need to display that content, but spiting the result on multiple `div` elements (pages).

For example:

One A4 page (a `div` tag) has aprox `width: 798px` and `height: 1128.6px`

If the html content inside that page is bigger in height than `1128.6px`, the "overflow" should be displayed on another page.

I am sure is possible to do this programmatically, but i am hoping for a css property, similar to [columns property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-count)

Comment: You cant have .6 pixels.

Comment: The value comes from the server as a decimal. Yes, probably browsers rounds it

Answer (score 2):

This is coming with CSS Regions-

> With Regions, you can use CSS properties to flow content into existing
>   styled containers, specifying any container order you choose,
>   regardless of their position on the page. Create visually stunning
>   responsive layouts for mobile and desktop content today.

See http://html.adobe.com/webplatform/layout/regions/

Support remains limited though, and this probably doesn't solve your requirements given dynamic content lengths.

This is almost certainly going to require either a server side or client side scripted (JavaScript) solution.

Comment: Thank you, looks very interesting, I'll have a look.

Comment: Unfortunately is not yet supported by any of the popular browsers:(